Getting gradle errir after reinstalling Android Studio and Java with newer version
I recently reinstalled Android studio and Java. Now my Flutter project is not running.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
      > Cannot get property 'apiLevel' on null object

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at C:\Users\VRS\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (6 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

